# Python - Reverse os.path.basename

Tags: python

Is there any way to reverse os.path.basename?

I have an attribute for my tree class like this:

```
self.root_ = os.path.basename(path)
```

and in a public method for the same tree class I would like to the find the whole path off of that one basename.

So for example:

```
my_path = F:\User\Word\TESTING\B
self.root_ = os.path.basename(my_path)
>>> B
"code to reverse this"
>>> F:\User\Word\TESTING\B
```

Comment: Short of looking through the entire file structure of every connected drive until you find it, no.

Comment: What if you have two identical filenames? Unless you keep the full directory (and then you may as well keep the full path), there is no way of knowing which of the two files it is.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah I figured so, was just curious